# Can't pass the error message from my cloud function to my front end

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a callable https cloud function for creating a new document (contact card). Before creating, I want to check that a contact card with the same phone number doesn't exist, and if it does, to abort the process and pass to the frontend an error with the message.

I can't find "error handling" documentation in the Firebase cloud function docs (I see some links in answers here but they all lead to 404 pages).
I've tried different configurations with `Promise.reject(new Error("My error message"))` and `throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.code, err.message, { message: err.message });` but haen't been able to get anything to work. What is the correct syntax?

In my frontend I call the function like this:

```
  const createNewContact = useCallback(
    async (
      newContactData: NewContactData,
      successCb: () => void,
      errorCb: (err: string) => void
    ) => {
      try {
        const contact= {
          phone_number: newContactData.phone_number,
          ...other data
        };

        const createContactCF = httpsCallable(functions, "createContact");
        await createContactCF(contact);

        successCb();
      } catch (err) {
        errorCb(err.message);
        console.log("Creating a new contact failed: ", err, err.message);
      }
    },
    [user]
  );
```

Then this is my cloud function:

```
exports.createContact = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const phoneNumber = data["phone_number"];

  if (!context.auth) {
    return Promise.reject(new Error("Only authenticated users can create a new contact"));
  }

  try {
    const snapshot = await db
      .collection("contacts")
      .where("phone_number", "==", phoneNumber )
      .get();

    if (!snapshot.empty) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Contact with the same phone number already exists"));
    }

    const newContactDoc = db.collection("contacts").doc();
    const newContact = await newContactDoc.set(data);


    return newContact;
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.code, err.message, {
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So what I didn't understand is that I needed to combine the two. Using async/await, throwing the error like this

```
   return Promise.reject(
      new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "unauthenticated",
        "Only authenticated users can......"
      )
    );
```

and then from my catch block as follows:

```
catch (err: any) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.code, err.message, {
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
```

Got the message I needed to my frontend.